# How can I configure postfix to allow relay for one specific recipient/destination email address?

Tags: postfix

My postfix install denies relaying. But I'd like to configure it to make an exception for one specific destination address or a specific domain?

For example, allow relaying of all messages from anyone destined for abc@example.com or @example.com, but continue to deny relaying for all other cases.

How would that exception be configured in postfix?

Comment: can you show us at least your postfix configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some trial and error but finally figured this out.

tested and confirmed on postfix versions 2.10.1 and 3.4.13.

start with a postfix server that blocks all relays.

to allow relaying for one specific recipient address, such as *abc@example.com*, create a file like, */etc/postfix/relay_recipients*.

in the file add the line: `abc@example.com x`

then create a lookup table using this command:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

then in *main.cf* add:

```
relay_domains = example.com
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

restart postfix.

now postfix will continue to block all relays, except when the recipient email address is *abc@example.com*.

Answer (score 0):

> allow relaying of all messages from anyone destined for abc@example.com or @example.com

Which parameter is used to configure relaying based on destination domain is explained in the manual:

https://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#relay_to

In other words, add example.com to `relayhost =`     separated with a comma and/or whitespace from any existing entries.

For a single address, no idea.